# Fixed Effects regression with trend and seasonality?

Tags: python, fixed-effects-model, seasonality, trend

I have monthly panel data on 8 tourist locations in the US (N=8), from 2011-2018 (T=84) and I would like to determine the impact of multiple independent variables (gas prices, income, etc) on recorded visits. The purpose is mainly to find evidence of a causal relationship rather than to perfectly forecast future values.

Based off what I can find, it seems that either a fixed-effects or first difference would be appropriate for this.

However, I see clearly that a linear increasing trend exists for all N across most variables, and that there is monthly seasonality to be accounted for as well. Based off readings in Wooldridge, typical ways to deal with this would be to:

- include a time trend- I do this by adding "Year" as an independent variable to remove trend, or FD
- adding dummy variables for each month to account for seasonality

My questions is:

- Would you agree with this approach to solving these issues? I don't see much consensus on trends and seasonality in panel data so I'm merely appropriating time-series approaches.
- Most independent variables are measured at a national level (gas prices, income) so there is no difference between tourist sites(N), would this cause issues?
- Lastly, the PanelOLS function which I'm using from python's [linearmodels](https://bashtage.github.io/linearmodels/panel/examples/examples.html) library, allows for the entity_fixed_effects=true to be specified and time fixed_effects to be specified. I'm mainly using entity fixed effects but is there any reason for time fixed effects to be specified?

Appreciate the help.

Comment: I'm thinking about a similar problem. I think a good exercise is to you may want to plot to if the trend seems linear, if so I think a "year" variable works otherwise you may need higher order trends. As for seasonality, I'd guess monthly or quarterly effects. I was also thinking about potentially deseasonalizing the variables for each subject (in your case location) via time series methods but can't seem to find much on the topic. This would be pretty similar to seasonal dummies and location fixed effects I think.